# How to take data .on change function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, model-view-controller

i have this function in MVC View:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    colSum55();
});

function colSum55() {
    var sumPP = 0;
    var x = ($("[name='popust']").val());
    var t = 0;

    $(".Total").each(function() {
        sumPP += parseFloat($(this).text());
    });
    t = (((sumPP) - ((sumPP) * (x / 100))));
    var y = 0;
    y = ($('#TotalPPO1').val((t).toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1.") + " €"));
}
$(function() {

    $("[name='popust']").on("change", function() {

        $("#TotalPPO").val($("#y").val());

    });
});
```

in this **function $("#y").val()** not take data, where is the problem?
  I want to take data on change value inputed in **name='popust'** field.

Comment: Probably `#y` isn't an element that can take a value … but you haven't provided a [mcve] so its hard to tell.

Comment: why question is not tagged with `jquery` you means forget to load jquery or any other resson??

Comment: Anyone solution about this ?

Comment: Thank you Hek mat i tagged jquery also.

Comment: @HelmerRashiti — We can't give you a solution with a [mcve]

Comment: @HelmerRashiti : Provide your HTML as well to get better solution.

Comment: @Nikhil Maheshwari  **[at]Html.TextBox("popust", "0", new { [at]id = "popust", style = "width:40pt", placeholder="0" }) %** and **<th colspan="2" ><input type="textbox" id="TotalPPO" class="foo" disabled="disabled"/></th>** Did you mean about this html ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved and here is the solution which i need:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                    colSum55();
                });
function colSum55() {
                        $("[name='popust']").on("change", function () {
                            var pp = 0;
                            pp = $("#popust1").val($(this).val());

                        var sumPP = 0;
                        var x = ($(pp).val());
                        var t = 0;
                        var y = 0;
                        //iterate through each input and add to sum
                        $(".Total").each(function () {
                            sumPP += parseFloat($(this).text());
                        });
                        t = (((sumPP) - ((sumPP) * (x / 100))));
                         $('#TotalPPO').html((t).toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1.") + " €");
                        });

                    }
```